# I have asked a question on Stack Overflow, but I can't see it

Tags: support, stack-overflow, questions, user-accounts

I can't see one of the questions that I have asked on Stack Overflow, it looks like the question doesn't exist.

The strange thing is that I have received an increase in reputation, so maybe someone liked my question or something like that.

What can I do?

Answer (score 9):

Your question

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6253981/whats-the-best-editor-vi-or-emacs

was closed by 5 users and deleted by a moderator as inappropriate for Stack Overflow.

See https://stackoverflow.com/faq